# Is there any necessity to use "once" or "when"?

Tags: conjunctions

I am wondering if we could say the original sentence as the revised ones, and if there is any difference in meaning among them?

> A.  When he broke his leg, he made a crutch for himself.
>
> B. Once  he broke his leg, he made a crutch for himself.

Original:

> Once, when he broke his leg, he made a crutch for himself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, yes, no and sort of... But wee need to examine the three sentences:

Original:

> Once, when he broke his leg, he made a crutch for himself.

This sentence gives *two* kinds of information, one temporal, one temporal or causal:

- *Time*: "Once he made a crutch." Once here means a singular point in time, in this case in the past.
- *Cause* or *time*: "when he broke his leg" Depending on how you choose to read the "when" it may also denote a cause, especially if you shift the tense in this subclause to "when he had broken".

Your first variety:

> When he broke his leg, he made a crutch for himself.

A simple sequence of events - break leg, make crutch. Not much different from the original, just simpler. The emphasis has shifted slightly to the *cause*.

Your second variety:

> Once he broke his leg, he made a crutch for himself.

Now here something nasty happens. Written like this, the *once* shifts his meaning to "as soon as". This sounds as if the person in the sentence had made some effort to break the leg (possibly on purpose) and *once* he managed to do so, he made the crutch.

If you re-write your second example, it doesn't help either:

> Once he broke his leg. He made a crutch for himself.

*Once* gets his original meaning of "at some point in time" back, but the two sentences loose their logic connection, so no alternative either.

Conclusion:

Stick with the original or your first variety, ditch the second.

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly correct to say:

> A. When he broke his leg, he made a crutch for himself.
>
> B. Once he broke his leg, he made a crutch for himself.

(Although A. is much preferable. B sounds like 'he was waiting for the moment his leg breaks, so that he could make himself a crutch'.

"Once, when he broke his leg, he made a crutch for himself" is like using the same word twice in a sentence. Here 'once' & 'when' mean the same and very is pretty much like repeating a word.